# Running functions automatically when certain criteria are met. Without user interaction.

Tags: python

I am using `Flask`.
I am currently using a `fabfile` to check which users should get a bill and I set up a cron job to run the `fabfile` every morning at 5am.  This automatically creates bills in Stripe and in my database and sends out emails to the users to inform them.  This could be used for birthday reminders or anything else similar.

**Is setting up a cronjob the standard way of doing this sort of thing? Is there a better way/standard?**

I would define "this sort of thing" as. Anything that needs to happen automatically in the app  when certain criteria are met without a user interacting with said app.

I could not find much when I googled this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `cron` is in effect the most straightforward way of doing it. However, there are other kind of services that trigger tasks on a periodic basis and offer some additional control. For instance, [Celery's scheduler](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html). There seems to be a tutorial about [building periodic tasks with celery here](http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/celery-periodic-tasks-installation-infinity).

Answer (score 0):

What *I think* you have to ask yourself is:

- Is a cron job the most reliable way of billing your customers?

I've written small/simple apps that use an internal timer. e.g: https://bitbucket.org/prologic/irclogger which roates it's irc log files once per day. Is this any better or more reliable? Not really; if the daemon/bot were to die prematurely or the system were to crash; what happens then? In this case it just gets started again and logs continue to rorate at the next "day" interval.

I think two things are important here:

- Reliability
- Robustness